# how to calculate modulus division

Tags: c, algorithm

I am stuck in a program while finding modulus of division.

Say for example I have:

```
((a*b*c)/(d*e)) % n
```

Now, I cannot simply calculate the expression and then modulo it to n as the multiplication and division are going in a loop and the value is large enough to not fit even in long long.

> <sub>As clarified in comments, n can be considered prime.</sub>

I found that, for multiplication, I can easily calculate it as:

```
((a%n*b%n)%n*c%n)%n
```

but couldn't understand how to calculate the division part then.

The problem I am facing is say for a simple example:

```
((7*3*5)/(5*3)) % 11
```

The value of above expression would be 7

but if I calculate the multiplication, modulo, it would be like:

```
((7%11)*(3%11))%11 = 10
((10%11)*(5%11))%11 = 6
```

now I am left with 6/15 and I have no way to generate correct answer.

Could someone help me. Please make me understand the logic by above example.

Comment: a%n = a - (n * int(a/n))

Comment: Use a large integer library.

Comment: (a/b)mod n = ((a mod n )( 1/b mod n) mod n )

Comment: @Randy There's no guarantee that `b` has an inverse mod n. E.g. `b=2, n=8`. Then there is no integer `x` such that `2*x % 8 == 1`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard correct - in that case the mod is undefined i think

Comment: Can you tell us more about where the values `a, b, c, d, e` (or whatever they are in your code) will come from and how they will change? There's no way to simplify it as is, but if we knew more we might be able to find a solution.

Comment: Hi iamnotmaynard, I am really sorry for lack of details here. The most confusion was about "n". I'll be using n as a prime number only, so solutions provided will seem to work. As already pointed out also tat if n is not prime we may get multiple/undefined solutions.

Comment: Ah yes, that is key. Then some of the answers given here will help. Will `n` be large or small?

Comment: i have also doubt about optimizing the code to find multiplicative index. Also, mentioned in the comments in answer of "jxh". But i think it is better to research a bit by myself and later start a new thread for that. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: Look up the **extended euclidean algorithm**. This is the way to compute inverses modulo a number (when they exist) if you cannot generate a table.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I am learning about extended euclidean algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 11 is prime, **Z**<sub>11</sub> is a field. Since `15 % 11` is `4`, `1/15` equals `3` (since `3 * 4 % 11` is 1). Therefore, `6/15` is `6 * 3` which is `7` mod 11.

In your comments below the question, you clarify that the modulus will always be a prime.

To efficiently generate a table of multiplicative inverses, you can raise `2` to successive powers to see which values it generates. Note that in a field **Z**<sub>p</sub>, where p is an odd prime, 2<sup>p-1</sup> = 1. So, for **Z**<sub>11</sub>:

```
 2^1 = 2
 2^2 = 4
 2^3 = 8
 2^4 = 5
 2^5 = 10
 2^6 = 9
 2^7 = 7
 2^8 = 3
 2^9 = 6
```

So the multiplicative inverse of `5` (which is 2<sup>4</sup>) is 2<sup>6</sup> (which is 9).

So, you can generate the above table like this:

```
power_of_2[0] = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    power_of_2[i] = (2*power_of_2[i-1]) % n;
}
```

And the multiplicative inverse table can be computed like this:

```
mult_inverse[1] = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    mult_inverse[power_of_2[i]] = power_of_2[n-1-i];
}
```

Comment: But `n` is not necessarily prime.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I didn't say this was a general solution, he wanted to understand how to generate the right answer from his example.

Comment: OP is looking for a general solution.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: General solution can probably be derived from the Chinese remainder theorem, but my number theory is too rusty at this point.

Comment: I think this could help me, just one question what if the denominator comes out to be 16. (16%11 = 5).

Comment: In a field, every non-zero element of the ring has a multiplicative inverse. The multiplicative inverse of `5` would be `9`.

Comment: great.. so to find the multiplicative inverse, do I need to have a loop from 1 to n-1 or there any efficient method??

Comment: @user2407394: You will need some kind of iteration, but it is not too bad. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user2407394: Be prepared to handle the absence of a solution, and multiple solutions, as outlined in my answer when the modulus is not prime.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: `n` is prime, according to comments under the question.

Comment: @jxh: Thank you; I see it now. That was posted an hour after my answer, but before my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, since 15 = 4 mod 11, you actually end up with having to evaluate (6/4) mod 11.

In order to find an exact solution to this, rearrange it as 6 = ( (x * 4)  mod 11), which makes clearer how the modulo division works.

If nothing else, if the modulus is always small, you can iterate from 0 to modulus-1 to get the solution.

Note that when the modulus is not prime, there may be multiple solutions to the reduced problem. For instance, there are two solutions to 4 = ( ( x * 2) mod 8): 2 and 6. This will happen for a reduced problem of form:

```
  a = ( (x * b) mod c)
```

whenever b and c are NOT relatively prime (ie whenever they DO share a common divisor).

Similarly, when b and c are NOT relatively prime, there may be no solution to the reduced problem. For instance, 3 = ( (x * 2) mod 8) has no solution. This happens whenever the *largest common divisor* of b and c does not also divide a.

These latter two circumstances are consequences of the integers from 0 to n-1 **not** forming a group under multiplication (or equivalently, a field under + and *) when n is **not prime**, but rather forming simply the less useful structure of a **ring**.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way the question is asked, it should be assumed that the numerator is divisible by the denominator.  In that case the finite field solution for prime n and speculations about possible extensions and caveats for non-prime n is basically overkill.  If you have all the numerator terms and denominator terms stored in arrays, you can iteratively test pairs of (numerator term, denominator term) and quickly find the greatest common divisor (gcd), and then divide the numerator term and denominator term by the gcd.  (Finding the gcd is a classical problem and you can easily find a simple solution online.)  In the worst case you will have to iterate over all possible pairs but at some point, if the denominator indeed divides the numerator, then you'll eventually be left with reduced numerator terms and all denominator terms will be 1.  Then you're ready to apply multiplication (avoiding overflow) the way you described.

Answer (score 2):

As n is prime, dividing an integer b is simply multiplying b's inverse. That is:

```
(a / b) mod n = (a * inv(b)) mod n
```

where

```
inv(b) = (b ^ (n - 2)) mod n
```

Calculating inv(b) can be done in O(log(n)) time using the [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm. Here is the code:

```
int inv(int b, int n)
{
    int r = 1, m = n - 2;
    while (m)
    {
        if (m & 1) r = (long long)r * b % n;
        b = (long long)b * b % n;
        m >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Why it works? According to Fermat's little theorem, if n is prime, b ^ (n - 1) mod n = 1 for any positive integer b. Therefore we have inv(b) * b mod n = 1.

Another solution for finding inv(b) is the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which needs a bit more code to implement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an O(log (n)) approach.Looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

*I think* you can distribute the division like

```
z = d*e/3
(a/z)*(b/z)*(c/z) % n
```

Remains only the integer division problem.

Comment: Why is the `/3` part of the answer?

Comment: No, you'd have to do the cubed root `z = (d*e) ** (1/3)`. (Or however it's done in C.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you had was that you picked a problem that was too simple for an example. In that case the answer was 7 , but what if a*b*c was not evenly divisible by c*d ? You should probably look up how to do division with modulo first, it should be clear to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing, think in terms of multiplicative inverses.  For each number in a mod-n system, there ought to be an inverse, if certain conditions are met.    For d and e, find those inverses, and then it's all just multiplying.   Finding the inverses is not done by dividing!  There's plenty of info out there...

Comment: There's no guarantee that b has an inverse mod n.